# Docker | Mounting volumes causes error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to setup a Docker swarm which connects 3 of my servers together. The swarm is setup and going to the URL I get the same result, which is perfect and just what I need.

However, for the server in which I am working on now I am producing a global nginx on every server in order to allow load balancing.

Sitting on the server will be multiple config files which I need in order to map the domain to the correct folder, which is the part which I am stuck on/not working for me.

I have a really simple `docker-compose.yml` as I have shrunk it in order to debug the issue, it consists of the following...

```
version: '3'
  services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/www/nginx/config/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

The volume is coming back with the error `"invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist"` so obviously when I remove the volume line it works perfectly, however I 100% need this line.

I can, inside of the server navigate perfectly to `/var/www/nginx/config/` and my config files exist within. Same with the other, if I run `docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash` and navigate to `/etc/nginx/conf.d` I can get to there perfectly fine which is why I'm posting on here.

I've looked at other posts and done what other people have said have fixed it such as

- Adding quotes to the volume
- Remove the slash at the end of the file
- Restart the server
- Restart Docker

But nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potential issue could be that not all the nodes in your swarm cluster have the directory (`/var/www/nginx/config/`) created. Since in swarm the service can be placed in any of the available nodes(unless you put in a constraint) you might be seeing this error.

Make sure that you have this directory created in all the 3 nodes.

Additionally you can also have a look [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax) for defining configs.